# Row_Number() Over this query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to include row numbers over this date range query. When I add the last row number sub query, it alters the results to be incorrect and I can't figure out why. Is there a better way to do this?

```
 DECLARE @MainHospital varchar(50) = 'Hospital1';

WITH Start AS
(
    SELECT 
           MAX(Time_Stamp) as StartDate, 
           DATEADD(day, 90, MAX(Time_Stamp)) as EndDate
    FROM Survey
    WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital

),
Results AS
(
   SELECT StartDate, EndDate from Start
   UNION
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EndDate), DATEADD(day, 91, EndDate) FROM Start
   UNION
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 92, EndDate), DATEADD(day, 182, EndDate) FROM Start
   UNION
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 183, EndDate), DATEADD(day, 273, EndDate) FROM Start
   UNION
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 274, EndDate), DATEADD(day, 364, EndDate) FROM Start
),
cte3 AS(
 SELECT LEFT(StartDate,11) AS StartDate, LEFT(EndDate,11) AS EndDate FROM Results
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StartDate) ranks,
StartDate, EndDate
FROM cte3
```

gives the following results, the beginning date is wrong. the December should be June10th since that is the max Time_Stamp.

```
    ranks                StartDate   EndDate
-------------------- ----------- -----------
1                    Dec  9 2014 Mar  9 2015
2                    Jun  9 2015 Sep  7 2015
3                    Jun 10 2014 Sep  8 2014
4                    Mar 10 2015 Jun  8 2015
5                    Sep  9 2014 Dec  8 2014
```

Comment: if you just want to truncate the time, just cast startdate AS date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that after you create CTE3, you are getting the dates as `varchar`values. Therefore, row number is sorting them alphabetically, not as dates. To fix this, cast as date during ordering like so:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CAST(StartDate as DATETIME)) ranks,
StartDate, EndDate
FROM cte3
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/GXT64154)

Even better, however, would be to keep `StartDate` and `EndDate` as `DateTime` values in CTE3 and converting them to string in the end, like so:

```
cte3 AS
(
 SELECT StartDate, EndDate FROM Results
)

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StartDate) ranks,
LEFT(StartDate,11) AS StartDate, LEFT(EndDate,11) AS EndDate
FROM cte3
```

Comment: You'd advocate keeping the conversion to string and the converting them *back* into `Datetime` rather than a) doing the row numbering first, or b) keeping both the string and the datetime values (in separate columns) in `CTE3`?

Comment: I would go with the first option when writing the query from scratch, but my first reaction was to provide a quick fix.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @MainHospital varchar(50) = 'Hospital1';

WITH Start AS
(
    SELECT 
           MAX(Time_Stamp) as StartDate, 
           DATEADD(day, 90, MAX(Time_Stamp)) as EndDate
    FROM Survey
    WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital

),
Results AS
(
   SELECT StartDate, EndDate from Start
   UNION
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, EndDate), DATEADD(day, 91, EndDate) FROM Start
   UNION
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 92, EndDate), DATEADD(day, 182, EndDate) FROM Start
   UNION
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 183, EndDate), DATEADD(day, 273, EndDate) FROM Start
   UNION
   SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 274, EndDate), DATEADD(day, 364, EndDate) FROM Start
),
cte3 AS(
 SELECT StartDate, EndDate FROM Results
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StartDate) ranks,
LEFT(StartDate,11) AS StartDate, LEFT(EndDate,11) AS EndDate
FROM cte3
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this section:

```
cte3 AS
(
 SELECT CAST(StartDate AS DATE) AS StartDate, CAST(EndDate AS DATE) AS EndDate FROM Results
)
```

No need to do the left 11 to just get the date portion.